# windows 10 cut off electricity then local disk D can t be accessed

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, file-corruption

It happened that the electricity was cut off and my laptop went off as it was not on battery. The problem I had afterwards is that the local disk D cannot be accessed `D : \ "is not accessible. the parameter is incorrect"` which is a serious problem, what are the best practices in this case? Also, disk D has installation files of many programs, when I lunach the laptop I can witness many programs being delayed, or not able to work at all, I can't also uninstall.

I went to cmd and tried chkdsk /f/r and it wrote that `Chkdsk cannot run because the volume is in use by another process. Would you like to schedule this volume to be checked the next time the system restarts? (Y/N)` and restarted. The problem still persists.

Comment: HDD or SSD? Fiddle as little with it as little as possible.

Comment: Not SSD,I don't know how to fiddle, I fear I might break the string

Comment: Best would be: clone drive (ddrescue) then recover data (files) from the clone or disk image file. This would be best practice.

Comment: That s cynical it seems, there is no way to fix it like a any other probelm?

Comment: I am not interested in recovery, but in access

Comment: Not ``cynical`` but ``prudent``.  @Joep is giving you **good** advice. 
 If that isn't what you want, of course you can *fix it like other problems*.  For example, to fix it like the problem of getting a nail to enter wood, hit it with a hammer several times.  I however would recommend solutions targeted at ***your*** specific problem.  Also pry bar will allow access without recovery.

Comment: @jii; Recovery is gaining access to lost data. This should be treated as a dataloss/datarecovery issue, that is, if you're interested in the data in D:.